# ruby installation 2.0.0 windows 8 no such file or directory dk.rb (loading error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, devkit

I am new to ruby and not a big fan of windows 8. I wanted to play around on ruby and got  windows 8 machine im using these tutorial but I cant get past the installation part .I have installed ruby 2.0.0 and the dev kit(DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe) but now every time i enter ruby dk.rb init in the comand prompt all I get is no such file or directory.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: In cmd prompt, type `ls`. If the file 'dk.rb' is not there, then navigate to where it is using `cd` and try again

Comment: iv just tried typing in ls then enter in command prompt and it said 'ls' not recognised as an internal or external command ,operable program or batch file

Comment: instead of "ls" use the windows equivalent directory command: "dir"

Comment: What happens when you enter "ruby -v" (no quotes)?  that will tell us if your system can find and run ruby.  You *should* see a result that tells you your ruby version -- something like "ruby 2.0.0.... [i386-minw32]"  (or whatever version of ruby you installed, and possibly [i386-minw64] if you installed the 64-bit version).  If your system can't find and run ruby, then you need to add it to your path.

Comment: thanks you iv found my version of ruby 2.0.0p598[x64-mingw32]

Comment: so if you go to the directory where dk.rb is, and then type 'dir' to confirm you're in the right directory, and then try to run it with 'ruby dk.rb' ... is it working?

Comment: Okay im in my dev kit directory and iv tried running it with ruby dk.rb and now what i get is no such file or directory loading error

Comment: iv manage to run ruby dk.rb successfully till i ran into this error after trying to perform gem install json --platform =ruby i got this error messeage    could not find a valid gem 'json' ( = 0) here is why unable to download data from